# You shuffle a standard 52-card deck, and you deal yourself two cards,

Tags: probability

You shuffle a standard 52-card deck, and you deal yourself two cards. Write each of the indicated answers as a fraction.

What is the probability both cards are aces?
What is the probability you deal yourself a pair (two cards of the same rank)?
What is the probability you deal yourself two cards of the same suit?

ok I figured out the first 2 but the last one is still giving me trouble

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: foor the first part I have tried multiplying 3/52 with 2/52 because I know that the two are dependent on each other but its not right? and I just really don't know what else to try...

Comment: Hint: we have $4$ aces, $13$ ranks and $4$ suits in a standard 52-card deck. Use combination.

Comment: well that would be my first mistake then

Comment: You aren't required to use combinations, but it is recommended that you become comfortable with either phrasing of the answer as when the questions get larger and more complicated you will save yourself lots of time by choosing the more appropriate phrasing.

Comment: As for the two cards both being the same suit... there are the two ways of phrasing it.  In the one way of phrasing, you might say "oh, well, if I draw the cards in sequence, the first card can be whatever... I don't care yet what it is.  Then, the next card will have to be from the same suit as the first, whatever that was"  In the other phrasing you might say "pick what suit, pick what two cards from that suit, and compare that to the number of ways of having picked two cards overall."

Comment: @RebecaLieYatsuzukaSilva That is a rather large number, not a probability.  Also, @ mad you say "*ok I figured out the first 2*".  What are your current answers to the first two then?

Comment: the first one is 1/221 and the second one is 1/17

Answer (score 1):

1) The probability of drawing two aces:

The first card will need to be an ace which occurs with probability $\frac{4}{52}$.  Then, the second card *from those remaining* will also need to be an ace.  Given that the first card was an ace, the second card will also be an ace with probability $\frac{3}{51}$.  (*Note, both the numerator decreased by one since there is one fewer ace, and the denominator also decreased by one since there is one fewer card overall*).  Multiplying these gives the probability:  $\frac{4}{52}\cdot \frac{3}{51}=\frac{1}{221}$

2) The first card can be whatever.  It doesn't matter what.  The second card will need to match the same rank as the first card, whatever the first card happened to be.  There are three remaining cards of that rank out of 51 cards overall, giving a probability of $\frac{3}{51}=\frac{1}{17}$

3) Exactly the same strategy as for problem 2 works.  The only difference is, rather than talking about 3 remaining cards of that rank being available we are instead worried about suit.  There are $12$ remaining cards of that suit available out of $51$ remaining cards overall, giving a probability of $\frac{12}{51} = \frac{4}{17}$

---

Phrasing differently with combinations and selecting the cards simultaneously, we could have instead phrased the answers as being:

1) choose which two aces and compare to the number of ways of picking two cards: $\frac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{52}{2}}$

2) choose which rank, then which two cards from that rank, and compare to the number of ways of picking two cards: $\frac{13\cdot \binom{4}{2}}{\binom{52}{2}}$

3) choose which suit, then which two cards from that suit, then compare to the number of ways of picking two cards: $\frac{4\cdot \binom{13}{2}}{\binom{52}{2}}$

These can be seen to equal exactly what we had before.

Answer (score 0):

What is the probability you deal yourself two cards of the same suit?

First card 13/52 Second Card 12/51. Then combined for the 4 suits :

(4 * 13 * 12) / 52 * 51 = 4/17.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the probability both cards are aces? What is the probability you deal yourself a pair (two cards of the same rank)? What is the probability you deal yourself two cards of the same suit?
>
> ok I figured out the first 2 but the last one is still giving me trouble

Why?  The second and third are evaluated in the same manner; just swapping suite and rank. There are 13 ranks of 4 suits, and 4 suits of 13 ranks.

Count ways you may obtain two cards from the same (rank/suite), when selecting two cards from the deck of fifty-two.